# OnlyOffice: Port forwarding

Tags: domain-name-system, port-forwarding

I'm setting up my own server and one of the things I'd like to run on it is OnlyOffice. However, I do not know how to properly configure my router and the DNS settings on my domain. I want onlyoffice.thijs365.com to point to the OnlyOffice installation on my server, but I'd also like to host a website on another server in my network. They both use ports 80 and 443. How do I do this? I'm running the community edition.

Thanks,
THijs365

Comment: If you want 2 servers running port 80, you're going to need 2 IP addresses.

Comment: How do I do that? And does an alternative method exist?

Comment: Well, if you're on a regular internet connection, with your home network behind nat, you can't, unless ipv6 only access is acceptable and supported for one of the servers

Comment: But I had to set a DNS Record (type: TXT) containing: portal-domain:i9JYk1qvOpVXxU0O. What’s that for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should post your issue on ONLYOFFICE Forum. Anyway, first of all you need to run Onlyoffice (docker) on another port (for example 8080).  You will be able to open Onlyoffice via http://yourdomain:8080 or you should configure proxy to redirect request from 80 to 8080.
Unfortunately i have no enough reputation to post with links.

Comment: Thanks. If I have a problem, then Stack Exchange is my go-to site. I’ll post it on the OnlyOffice forum.